# Cosmos client - Binding or DI?

Tags: azure-functions

What is the recommended practice of using Cosmos client in a function app -

(1) Register a singleton in a function start-up class's service collection and constructor-inject it in functions' class.  I am assuming I can use newest Cosmos SDK to create it;

(2) Use Cosmos binding features, which allow you get client from binding if you need more control over queries.  This also allows you to use CosmosTrigger for feed processing;

(3) Mix (1) and (2).

The reason I am asking is Cosmos is now on newer SDK than the version used by Azure Functions bindings, and has some features I'd like to use like streaming iterators.  I am tempted to use option (3), i.e. use both the injection and bindings where appropriate, but wouldn't it create two singleton Cosmos clients (one for 3.* sdk (DI) and one for 2.* for bindings)? Is it bad?  If I use option (1) and go with my own injected client, would CosmosTrigger still require "old" sdk client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings are purely a convenience and behind the scenes are doing exactly what you describe in #1. So if you want to use the newer version of the SDK or just like having more control over how things are instantiated go with #1. You won’t lose anything by it.

Triggers are slightly different only because it has to use the SDK included to trigger the function. So behind the scenes the Functions Host will spin up a `CosmosClient` in this case and use it to pull messages.  While it may work with newer versions specified, it is something to be aware that it may break too (would break locally and in cloud so you should be able to confirm pretty quickly).  So in general if using as an input or output binding, totally fine to pull in whatever version of SDK you want.  If you are using for trigger, it’s recommended to stick with the version pulled in by the extension (and ideally the extensions should be updated frequently to provide the latest versions of SDK as well).

Comment: But then if I use CosmosDb trigger, it would create its own client based on older sdk, would it not? Maybe it's not a big deal, just wanted to make sure I am not creating a mess of mixing different sdks.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  Behind the scenes it will attempt to create its own client. It’s even possible that if you pull in a newer version the extension may throw some errors if it’s incompatible. So triggers does present a bit less of a “just a convenience”. But luckily extensions can be versioned as well so ideally the cosmos trigger would release an update on latest as well

Comment: So, if you need to use Cosmos trigger in your function app, which is available in `WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB`, then the best practice would be to stick with whatever version of the Cosmos SDK the extension is using (currently 2.3), correct? Having both `WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB` and `Azure.Cosmos` dependencies may lead to conflicts, unless both depend on same sdk version.

Comment: Ok, thx - if you want to update your answer to reflect the above comments, I'll accept it, otherwise we can leave it as is.  Also, I know you are on a AF team, so if you guys can work on updating `WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB` to use newer sdk, that would be awesome too :)

Comment: Actually I found this in cosmos db docs (must've missed it on first read-through) - "If want to use the Azure Cosmos DB SDK, make sure that you don't add to your project another NuGet package reference. Instead, let the SDK reference resolve through the Azure Functions' Extension package. Consume the Azure Cosmos DB SDK separately from the trigger and bindings".  -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-changefeed-functions.  This kinda answers my questions.

Comment: Yep that’s great - also updated my answer and yes have a work item to rev these extensions to latest and greatest SDK versions (just finishing work to bring Event Hubs and Service Bus to the latest versions)

Comment: @jeffhollan does the "only convenience" factor still hold today and is also true for python and the v2 programming model? i actually see a lot more convenience in just using the cosmosclient. the more i use bindings, the less i want to use them.